# How can I use the natural logarithm in ggplot axis tick labels instead of log10?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found I can use  `scale_x_log10()` to use the base10 logarithm, but I would like to use the natural logarithm instead. How can I accomplish this? I only want to change how the plot is scaled, without modifying the underlying values being plotted.

Here's a minimal example with a dataset

```
set.seed(42)
data.frame(exp=rexp(100,5)*10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=exp)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scales::log_trans` (which has a `base` argument defaulting to the natural log).

```
set.seed(42)
data.frame(exp=rexp(100,5)*10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=exp)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6), trans = scales::log_trans())
```

[image]

You can also create your own function `scale_x_ln`

```
scale_x_ln <- function(...) scale_x_continuous(..., trans = scales::log_trans())
set.seed(42)
data.frame(exp=rexp(100,5)*10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=exp)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_ln(breaks = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6))
```

giving the same result.